# How to display xmltype columns as table

Tags: oracle, xmltype, xmltable

I have the XML type values as below structure

```
<row id=“124”>
<c1>Name</c1>
<c2>Name2</c2>
</row>
```

The columns is not fixed and it will be different for each record.

Expected result is
Result
Name
Name2

Answer (score 1):

You could use wild cards and positions to get whatever value is in each node, providing as many `columns` clauses as you might possible have nodes under a row, and each of those defined as string with the maximum length you expect from any column (maybe 4000, but 30 here for brevity):

```
select *
from xmltable (
  '/row'
  passing xmltype('<row id="124">
<c1>Name</c1>
<c2>Name2</c2>
</row>')
  columns
    col1 varchar2(30) path '*[1]',
    col2 varchar2(30) path '*[2]',
    col3 varchar2(30) path '*[3]'
);

COL1                           COL2                           COL3                          
------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------
Name                           Name2
```

And you could then unpivot that to get the output you stated, again with as many `unpivot` clauses as you have XMLTable `columns` clauses:

```
select result
from xmltable (
  '/row'
  passing xmltype('<row id="124">
<c1>Name</c1>
<c2>Name2</c2>
</row>')
  columns
    col1 varchar2(30) path '*[1]',
    col2 varchar2(30) path '*[2]',
    col3 varchar2(30) path '*[3]'
)
unpivot (result for x in (col1 as 1, col2 as 2, col3 as 3));

RESULT                        
------------------------------
Name
Name2
```

You could also do a separate XMLQuery call for each row and union them together, but that seems more complicated and less efficient.

If your data is in a table then you can extend that - here with a CTE to represent the table:

```
with your_table(xml_col) as (
  select xmltype('<row id="124">
<c1>Name</c1>
<c2>Name2</c2>
</row>')
  from dual
  union all
  select xmltype('<row id="125">
<x>Value X</x>
<y>Value Y</y>
<z>999</z>
</row>')
  from dual
)
select id, result
from your_table t
cross join xmltable (
  '/row'
  passing t.xml_col
  columns
    id number path '@id',
    col1 varchar2(30) path '*[1]',
    col2 varchar2(30) path '*[2]',
    col3 varchar2(30) path '*[3]'
) x
unpivot (result for x in (col1 as 1, col2 as 2, col3 as 3));

        ID RESULT                        
---------- ------------------------------
       124 Name                          
       124 Name2                         
       125 Value X                       
       125 Value Y                       
       125 999
```

You could also extend this to include the original node name, which might be helpful for understanding the values:

```
with your_table(xml_col) as (
...
)
select id, col, result
from your_table t
cross join xmltable (
  '/row'
  passing t.xml_col
  columns
    id number path '@id',
    col1_name varchar2(30) path '*[1]/local-name()',
    col2_name varchar2(30) path '*[2]/local-name()',
    col3_name varchar2(30) path '*[3]/local-name()',
    col1 varchar2(30) path '*[1]',
    col2 varchar2(30) path '*[2]',
    col3 varchar2(30) path '*[3]'
) x
unpivot (
  (col, result) for x in (
    (col1_name, col1) as 1, (col2_name, col2) as 2, (col3_name, col3) as 3
  )
);

        ID COL                            RESULT                        
---------- ------------------------------ ------------------------------
       124 c1                             Name                          
       124 c2                             Name2                         
       125 x                              Value X                       
       125 y                              Value Y                       
       125 z                              999
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=700872099a57620eb2bc779589098a0b), though the version that is running seems to have a bug in the display of the intermediate (pre-unpivot) results from a table, so I've shown with both a table and CTE for those.